# How do I align text with the top of the image?

Tags: html, css, css-float, text-alignment

I have an image on the left and I'd like to line up the text to the top of the image.

I have the code below in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/30wk0x8h/) jsfiddle:

```
<div>
   <img src... >
   <span>hello  hello hello hello hello hello...</span> 
</div>
```

But it aligns the text along the bottom of the image, like this:

[image]

How do I flow the text around the image from the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical case to use [float](http://%20hello%20hello%20hello%20hello%20hello%20hello%20hello%20hello%20hello%20hello%20hello%20hello%20hello%20hello):

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be placed along the left or right side of its container, allowing text and inline elements to wrap around it.

Simply add `float: left;` to your `<img>` element and the text will start from the top of the image.

```css
img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/E8117F/000.png">
  <span style="vertical-align:text-top">hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following css to your fiddle aligned the text with the top of the image. Is this what you are looking for? If not please add more details and I can edit my answer.

```
img {
  float: left;
}
```

```css
img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/E8117F/000.png">
  <span style="vertical-align:text-top">hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Floating the image would be useful:
https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

```css
.media img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="media">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/E8117F/000.png">
    <span>hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello</span>
<span>hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello</span>
</div>
```